# Combine 2 render into 1 render in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have two components in the render function.

If the second component has height higher than the first component, hide the second component

Below is the snippet I wrote:

```
isOverflow = () => {
    const { component1, component2 } = this;

if (component2.clientHeight > component1.clientHeight) {
  this.setState({ isOverflow: true });
 } else {
      this.setState({ isOverflow: false });
    }
  }
```

See my snippet in my render function.

```
<div ref={ref => (this.component1 = ref)}</div>

<div ref={ref => (this.component2 = ref)} style={{ visibility: !isOverflow ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}>
```

And I face a problem here, in React I need to render at least 1 time to get the height, and I need another render to hide the component.

This implementation looks ugly because it is like showing an animation (2 renders)

Can I achieve both in 1 render only?

[Note: The height is a dynamic value. Therefore, I cannot achieve this by CSS. I must use Javascript here.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deciding the render on `componentDidMount` because the DOM references are available at this point.

See "React updates ­D­O­M and refs" [component lifecycle diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).

[image]

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.setState({ hide: this.component2.clientHeight > this.component1.clientHeight });
};

<>
  <div ref={(ref) => (this.component1 = ref)} />
  <div
    ref={(ref) => (this.component2 = ref)}
    style={{ visibility: this.state.hide ? "hidden" : "visible" }}
  />
</>
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought componentDidMount only run when there is a first render.

Comment: I verify your code and I am sure it is not working.  The value of this.component2.clientHeight and this.component1.clientHeight are 0. They only have value in the second render

Comment: Do you have reproducible example in a sandbox? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)

Comment: After testing for half an hour, yes your code is working. But on my page, there is a header and body. There are a few lines of code in the header only. ComponentDidMount function in header is unable to get the height position because the body still haven't load everything.

Comment: I answer what you asking, if there is side effects its a different question. Better ask a new question with more specifics.